# Calculation of the Impulse of the force

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, momentum

can we calculate impulse of the force acting on a particle for a time interval using using Newton's 2nd Law which is described as Force acting on a particle equals mass of the particle times acceleration of the particle during that time interval?

Comment: Actually, Newton originally used the equation $F=\Delta p/\Delta t$, which is a slightly different form of the equation $F=ma$.  Use a bit of dimensional analysis, and you will see that these two functional forms are equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

***Can we calculate impulse of the force acting on a particle for a time interval using Newton's 2nd Law which is described as Force acting on a particle equals mass of the particle times acceleration of the particle during that time interval?***

From Newton’s second law

$$F_{\text{average}}=ma_{\text{average}}=m\frac{\Delta v}{\Delta t}$$

The impulse of force is defined as

$$\text{Impulse}=F_{\text{average}}\Delta t$$

Combining the two we have

$$\text{Impulse}=m\Delta v$$

So you can determine the impulse of force if you know the average force and the duration of its application or, alternatively, if you know the change in momentum. For a given change in momentum the impulse of force remains constant if the mass is constant.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

By definition the Impulse produced by a force acting on a body for a time interval is the integral of the force over that time interval.

This is a basic definition and Newton's laws are not needed (or necessarily useful) to calculate this.  What is needed is F(t), force as a function of time.  If this is not known then one typically uses some reasonable constant, the average value or peak value, over the entire interval.  Then Impulse = F*(t2 - t1).

This quantity measure that change in momentum of the object due to the force F(t).

This type of description usually makes sense (or makes more sense) to use when there is a contact force between two objects over a very short duration, as in collisions.

As for making use of acceleration?  Let's say you were able to measure the acceleration of a mass (an you know the mass) over a short duration.  Then yes, you could use m*a and dt to figure out the impulse delivered to the object.